# how oat++ String::loadFromFile deal with `\0`

Tags: oat++

when I use `oatpp::String::loadFromFile()`，a question comes to my mind: How `loadFromFile` deal with `\0`?

I look up the source code and find `loadFromFile` read file in binary mod, and then cast the file data into `char` and build a `oatpp::String` object return.

if there is occasionally 8bit `0` in the file and `loadFromFile` cast it into `char` and build `oatpp::String` from it, the content of file may be cut since it contain a `\0` in string body.

```cpp
auto s = oatpp::String::loadFromFile(FILEPATH)
createResponse(Status::CODE_200, s)
```

I would like to know if the above scenario will happen, If so, Is there any good way to fill response body with byte stream directly?

Answer (score 0):

`oatpp::String` is NOT a null-terminated string.
oatpp will load the full content of the file to string and will return the full content in response.

From `loadFromFile()` implementation:

```
String String::loadFromFile(const char* filename) {
  std::ifstream file (filename, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
  if (file.is_open()) {
    auto result = data::mapping::type::String(file.tellg()); //<-- create string of size of file size.
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    file.read((char*) result->data(), result->size()); //<-- read the whole file into string's buffer
    file.close();
    return result;
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```